# Is using "those" to refer to "something" (a pair) correct?

Tags: grammatical-number

Is "Those shoes don't seem like something you should buy" correct?

I'm assuming it's ok because the "something" is a pair (plural)?

Comment: Yes. When referring to as a pair.

Comment: *Shoes* is plural: "Those shoes are...".  A pair is singular: **"*That pair* of shoes *is*** something you should buy."

Comment: _Shoes, trousers, binoculars, (eye)glasses, (under)pants_ [US], etc. are all **dual** number and take plural agreement, even when they are obviously single units, like trousers. Duals have many peculiarities; _both_ is a dual, for instance, and so are _couple_ and _pair_.

Comment: You can say, though, "that pot doesn't look like something you should buy."--where "pot" is singular, of course.

Answer (score 3):

You will need a plural verb ("don't" as opposed to "doesn't"), but the reason has nothing to do with the shoes coming in a pair.  It's simply because the subject is plural ("shoes" as opposed to "shoe" or "pair").

Note the difference:

> That pair of shoes doesn't seem like something you should buy.

This is called *subject-verb agreement*.  It works exactly the same as in a simpler sentence, for example:

> Those shoes are snazzy.
>
> That pair of shoes is snazzy.

Comment: The grammatical dual number dropped out of English (and most Indo-European languages) well over a thousand years ago, IIRC.   Old English had *ic* (I), *wit* (we two), and *we* (we three or more); and also *thou*, *yit* (you two), and *ye* (you three or more), but in both cases the dual form was assimilated to the plural.